# Primitive console string calculator in C

Tags: c, calculator, math-expression-eval

Recenlty I have finished this primitive console string calculator in C. I need your balanced criticism, I'd like to know what I have to correct, remake and learn.

> Permitted operations: `+ - * / ( ) ^`
>
> Sample input string: `11 * -10 + 15 - 35 / (35 - 11) + 2^2 =`

***main.c***

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "calculating.h"
#include <errno.h>

#define EXPR_LENGTH 1000

main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        Stack* nums = createEmptyStack();
        ValType lastval, prevval, result;
        char* temp = NULL, temp_char;
        char num_buf[NUM_LENGTH], expr_buf[EXPR_LENGTH];
        CalcErrors err_flag = NO_ERR;

        system("cls"); // clear the screen
        printf("Enter the expression: ");

        /* Transform the infix notation to the reverse Polish notation and processing the error if necessary */
        if (transformToRPN(expr_buf) != NO_ERR) {
            err_flag = WRONGSYM_ERR;
            goto break_loop;
        }

        temp = expr_buf; // to don't change the pointer expr_buf

        /* Parsing the operands from expression in the reverse Polish notation */
        while (temp_char = getOperand(num_buf, temp, &temp))
        {
            switch (temp_char) {
                /* Processing the operators */
            case SUB: case ADD: case MUL: case POW: case DIV:
                if (nums->size < 2) { // if operators are less than 2 (to avoid a pop() of empty stack)
                    err_flag = LACK_OPERAND;
                    goto break_loop; // break the nested loop
                }

                lastval = pop(nums); // last added operand
                prevval = pop(nums);

                result = useOperator(prevval, lastval, temp_char);

                if (errno || (!lastval && temp_char == DIV)) { // math errors (out of range, zero division etc)
                    err_flag = MATH_ERR;
                    goto break_loop; // break the nested loop
                }

                push(nums, result);
                break;

                /* Adding a value in the stack */
            case VAL:   push(nums, atof(num_buf));  break;
                /* End of input or other errors */
            case EQ:    err_flag = END_CALC;        goto break_loop;
            default:    err_flag = WRONGSYM_ERR;    goto break_loop;
            }
        }

    break_loop: // if input was incorrect, loop will be broken

        printf("\n");

        /* Processing the errors or displaying an answer */
        switch (err_flag) {
        case WRONGSYM_ERR:  printf(MSG_WRONGSYM); break;
        case MATH_ERR:          printf(MSG_MATH); break;
        case END_CALC:      nums->size == 1 ? printf("= %f\n", pop(nums)) : printf(MSG_LACKOP); break;
        case LACK_OPERAND:  printf(MSG_LACKOP); break; // FIX THE TEXT
        }

        printf("\nDo you want to calculate something else? y/n > ");

        getchar(); // skip the '\n' symbol
        temp_char = getchar();

        if (temp_char != 'y' && temp_char != 'Y')
            break;
    }
}
```

***stack.h***

```
#define ELEMENTARY_SIZE_STACK 5 // initial the length of stack
#define RESIZE_ADDING 5 /* how much will be add when the stack size 
                            will be equal to ELEMENTARY_SIZE */
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define ValType double
#define ValType_IOSPECIF "%lf"

typedef struct stack
{
    ValType* data;
    size_t max; // such value when the stack size should be extend
    size_t size;
} Stack;

Stack*      createEmptyStack(void);
void        push(Stack* s, ValType val);
void        deleteStack(Stack* st);
static void resize(Stack* st);
ValType     pop(Stack* st);
ValType     peek(Stack* st);
void        printStack(Stack* st);

#define MSG_MALLOC "ERROR! MALLOC RETURNS NULL!\n"
#define MSG_REALLOC "ERROR! REALLOC RETURN NULL!\n "
```

***calculating.h***

```
#include <float.h>

/* Errors processing */
typedef enum calcerr {
    NO_ERR,
    MATH_ERR,
    WRONGSYM_ERR,
    LACK_OPERAND,
    END_CALC
} CalcErrors;

#define MSG_WRONGSYM "ERROR! You entered the wrong symbol(s).\n"
#define MSG_LACKOP  "ERROR! The input format is not correct.\n"
#define MSG_MATH "ERROR! Math error!\n"

/* Operators, delimiters, other characters */
#define VAL 1
#define SUB '-'
#define ADD '+'
#define MUL '*'
#define DIV '/'
#define EQ '='
#define POW '^'
#define OP_BRACE '('
#define CL_BRACE ')'

#define DELIM_DOT '.'
#define DELIM_COMMA ','
#define IS_DELIM(x) ((x) == DELIM_DOT || (x) == DELIM_COMMA)

#define SPACE ' '

/* Priority of operators */
#define PRIOR_SUB 1                 
#define PRIOR_ADD 1
#define PRIOR_MUL 2
#define PRIOR_DIV 2
#define PRIOR_POW 3
#define PRIOR_OP_BR 0
#define PRIOR_CL_BR 0

#define PRIOR(x) getPriority(x)

/*Calculation and parsing expressions on the RPN (Reverse Polish Notation) */
int     getOperand(char* num, char expression[], char** end);
double  useOperator(double leftval, double rightval, char oper);

/*transform the infix notation to the reverse Polish notation*/
int         isOperator(char op);
static int  getPriority(char op);
CalcErrors  transformToRPN(char result[]); 

#define NUM_LENGTH DBL_DIG // maximum length of number
```

***calculating.c***

```
#include "calculating.h"
#include "stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Function for working with an expression on the RPN */

int getOperand(char* num, char expression[], char** end)
{
    unsigned counter = 0;
    char* ptr = expression;

    /* NULL pointer checking*/
    if (!ptr) return 0;

    /* Spaces skipping before */
    while (isspace(*ptr))
        ptr++;

    /* The unary minus checking */
    int negative_flag = 0;
    if (*ptr == SUB)
    {
        if (isdigit(*++ptr))   // if the next character is a digit
            negative_flag = 1;
        else
            ptr--;
    }

    /* The return of the any not digit character */
    if (!isdigit(*ptr))
    {
        *end = ++ptr;
        return *(ptr - 1);
    }

    /* Making a float number and the delimiter processing */
    while (isdigit(*ptr) || IS_DELIM(*ptr))
    {
        if (*ptr == DELIM_COMMA)
            *ptr = DELIM_DOT; // for atof()

        if (negative_flag)
        {
            num[counter++] = SUB;
            negative_flag = 0; // in order to add the minus symbol one time in the head of array
        }

        num[counter++] = *ptr;
        ptr++;
    }

    num[counter] = '\0';
    *end = ptr; // pointer to the next character (to continue reading an operand from a new location)
    return VAL;
}

double useOperator(double leftval, double rightval, char oper)
{
    double result;
    switch (oper) {
    case ADD: result = leftval + rightval; break;
    case SUB: result = leftval - rightval; break;
    case MUL: result = leftval * rightval; break;
    case DIV: result = leftval / rightval; break;
    case POW: result = pow(leftval, rightval); break;
    default: exit(1);
    }

    return result;
}

/* Function for working with an expression on the infix notation */

int getPriority(char ch) {
    switch (ch) {
    case SUB: return PRIOR_SUB;
    case ADD: return PRIOR_ADD;
    case MUL: return PRIOR_MUL;
    case DIV: return PRIOR_DIV;
    case POW: return PRIOR_POW;
    case OP_BRACE: return PRIOR_OP_BR; // opening parethesis
    case CL_BRACE: return PRIOR_CL_BR; // closing parethesis
    default: return -1;
    }
}

int isOperator(char x)
{
    return (x == SUB || x == ADD || 
            x == MUL || x == DIV || 
            x == POW);
}

CalcErrors transformToRPN(char result[])
{
    Stack* ops = createEmptyStack();
    char temp_ch;
    unsigned counter = 0;

    while ((temp_ch = getchar())) 
    { 
        /* Spaces skipping before */
        while (isspace(temp_ch))  
            temp_ch = getchar();

        /* Ending the input, fully write the remaining contents of stack*/
        if (temp_ch == EQ) 
        {
            while (ops->size)
            { 
                result[counter++] = (char)pop(ops);
                result[counter++] = SPACE;
            }
            result[counter++] = EQ;
            result[counter] = '\0';
            return NO_ERR;
        }

        /* Cheking the unary minus, and if it's not unary, return character after minus used to check back 
        and process a minus as an operator*/
        if (temp_ch == SUB)
        {
            temp_ch = getchar(); // read next symbol and if the next character is a digit
            if (isdigit(temp_ch)) { 
                if (temp_ch != '0') // to don't allow the '-0'
                    result[counter++] = SUB;
            }
            else {
                ungetc(temp_ch, stdin);
                temp_ch = SUB;
            }
        }

        /* Making a number */
        if (isdigit(temp_ch))
        {
            while (isdigit(temp_ch) || IS_DELIM(temp_ch) )
            { 
                result[counter++] = temp_ch;
                temp_ch = getchar();
            }   
            ungetc(temp_ch, stdin); // return the extra character
            result[counter++] = SPACE;
        }

        /* Else check the operator and push it to the stack */
        else 
        {
            if (isOperator(temp_ch)) 
            {
                if (!ops->size) // if stack is empty (to avoid an error after pop)
                    push(ops, (double)temp_ch);
                else 
                {
                    if (PRIOR(temp_ch) <= PRIOR((char)peek(ops))) // > if priority of new operator is higher than operator 
                    {                                             // in the top of stack, then the old operation will be
                        result[counter++] = (char)pop(ops);       // display and new operator push in the stack < 
                        result[counter++] = SPACE;
                    }

                    push(ops, (double)temp_ch);
                }
            }
            /* Operators inside parathesises processing */
            else if (temp_ch == OP_BRACE)
                push(ops, (double)temp_ch);
            else if (temp_ch == CL_BRACE)  // if it's a closing parethesis, then it write all of operators before the
            {                              // opening parethesis not including it
                char tmp;
                while ((tmp = (char)pop(ops)) != OP_BRACE) // until the opening parathesis
                {
                    result[counter++] = tmp;
                    result[counter++] = SPACE;
                }
            }
            /* Any other symbols */
            else  
                return WRONGSYM_ERR;
        }   
    }
}
```

***stack.c***

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <string.h>
Stack* createEmptyStack(void)
{
    Stack* st = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if (st == NULL) {
        printf(MSG_MALLOC);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    st->data = malloc(sizeof(ValType)*ELEMENTARY_SIZE_STACK);
    if (st->data == NULL) {
        printf(MSG_MALLOC);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    st->max = ELEMENTARY_SIZE_STACK; 
    st->size = 0;
    return st;
}

void deleteStack(Stack* st)
{
    free(st->data);
    free(st);
    st = NULL;
}

static void resize(Stack* st)
{
    st->max += RESIZE_ADDING;
    st->data = realloc(st->data, st->max*sizeof(ValType));
    if (st->data == NULL) {
        printf(MSG_REALLOC);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void push(Stack* st, ValType val)
{
    if (st->size == st->max)
        resize(st);
    st->data[st->size++] = val;
}

ValType pop(Stack* st)
{
    if (!st->size) { // if there is a request to pop the value from empty stack
        printf("ERROR (FUNCTION POP): STACK SIZE < 0\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    st->size--;
    return st->data[st->size];
}

/* In this function just look to the top of the stack */
ValType peek(Stack* st)
{
    if (!st->size) { // if there is a request to pop the value from empty stack
        printf("ERROR (FUNCTION PEEK): STACK SIZE < 0\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return st->data[st->size-1];
}

void printStack(Stack* st)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < st->size; i++)
        printf(ValType_IOSPECIF " ",st->data[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Generalities and trivialities:

I recommend `#include`ing all wanted system headers before any private headers.  This avoids any possibility of changing the meaning of any system header by defining a macro that happens to be meaningful to it.

`static` functions and variables generally should *not* be declared in header files, unless you actually want every file that includes the header to provide (for functions) or have (for variables) its own copy.  In your code, this applies to the `resize()` and `getPriority()` functions.  If you want to prototype those then put each prototype near the top of the C file where the corresponding function definition appears.

The string constant for `MSG_REALLOC` contains a trailing space character that you probably did not intend.

There's no point in `deleteStack()` setting its argument to `NULL`, as the caller will not see any effect of it.

On the other hand, you never call `deleteStack()` or `printStack()`.  Inasmuch as this is a program, not a reusable library, it is wasteful to define functions that you never call.

You do not declare the type of `main()`.  It does default to `int`, which is the required type, but failing to declare that is poor style.

It looks like you could replace much of function `getOperand()` with a call to `strtod()`.

### Regarding `ValType`:

If you see value in defining the value data type as a macro -- and I think that may be a bit overkill -- then at least define it *conditionally*.  The point of using a macro would be to make it easy to switch to a different type, and you've gone only half way on that.  If you make the definition(s) conditional, then it would not be necessary to modify the header at all to change type.  For example:

```
#idndef ValType
#define ValType double
#endif

#ifndef
#define ValType_IOSPECIF "%f"
#endif
```

Note in the above example code that I have changed the default definition of `ValType_IOSPECIF`.  The result is the correct form, per the standard, for a `printf()` field descriptor for a `double` (there is none specific to `float` because `float` arguments to `printf()` are automatically promoted to `double`, as a consequence of those falling among `printf()`'s variable arguments).  Note also that `printf()` and `scanf()` are asymmetric in this particular regard, so if you needed to support both then you would need separate macros for the two contexts.

### Regarding function `transformToRPN()`:

Function `transformToRPN()` does not just transform an expression, it *inputs* one.  At minimum, therefore, the function is poorly named, but it's questionable that these two behaviors are combined in a single function.

In function `transformToRPN()`, you have an `else` block whose sole contents is an `if/elseif/else` tree, and moreover, that conditions in that inner tree test the same variable that those on the outer tree do.  I recommend merging the inner tree into the outer tree for clarity and symmetry.

Function `transformToRPN()` receives a pointer to a buffer into which to record an RPN transformation of the input expression, but it does not receive the size of that buffer, and it performs no bounds checking.  It would be extremely easy for a user to intentionally cause a buffer overrun, which is a favorite cracking tactic.

Function `transformToRPN()` assigns the return value of `getchar()`, an `int`, to a variable of type `char`.  If `char` happens to be a signed type, then this produces implementation-defined behavior for some possible inputs.  Whether `char` is signed or unsigned, you cannot distinguish one possible input char from an `EOF`.

Moreover, the `while()` loop seems unlikely to terminate, because at the end of the stream `getchar()` returns `EOF`, which normally has value `-1`, and *always* has a value outside those that can result from converting a valid `char` value, including 0, to type `unsigned char`.  The loop will terminate only if `getchar()` returns `0`.

Comment: The `free(st); st = NULL;` is a developing style that encourages early (fault) detection of dereferencing `st` later in code.  True that in `deleteStack()`, there is no later code.  Yet setting a pointer to `NULL` after `free()` is a defensive coding practice  - which should be encouraged.  I would even re-design `void deleteStack(Stack* st)` --> `void *deleteStack(Stack* st)` or `void deleteStack(Stack** st)` to allow the calling code to benefit from this `NULL` assignment.

Answer (score 9):

#### Design

1. `#define VAL 1 #define SUB '-' #define ADD '+'` etc. are too generically named.  Suggest a naming convention that does not so readily conflict with other code.  Same for function names `push(), resize(), pop(), peek()`.  In general, the .h files add name all over the name-space.  Suggest a corner of it instead.
2. I would expect code guards in the .h files

   ```
   // or some uppercase variant
   #ifndef stack_h
   #define stack_h
      ....body of .h file
   #endif
   ```
3. Rather than allocating per the size of the type, allocate based on the size of the variable.  Less error prone and easier to maintain.

   ```
   //Stack* st = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
   //st->data = malloc(sizeof(ValType)*ELEMENTARY_SIZE_STACK);
   Stack* st = malloc(sizeof *st);
   st->data = malloc(sizeof *(st->data) * ELEMENTARY_SIZE_STACK);
   ```
4. Unclear why code is avoiding `-0`.  No need for that.

   ```
   if (temp_ch != '0') // to don't allow the '-0'
   ```
5. `getOperand()` does not seem to allow `.123` as input.  I would expect this to pass.

#### Minor Stuff

1. Suggest `bool` return type for `isOperator()`.
2. The test for a `,` to change it into `.` for `atof()` is interesting, yet a problem.  `atof()` accepts a `,`  or `.` depending on *locale*.  I would not folding these two characters together without checking *locale* and then calling a *locale* sensitive function.
3. Missing check for unary `+`.  Code check for unary `-`.  Complete code would check for both.
4. Ensure code passes a value in the range of `unsigned` char to `isspace()`.  Aside from `EOF`, passing negative value to `isspace()` is UB.

   ```
   // while (isspace(*ptr))
   while (isspace((unsigned char) *ptr))
   ```
5. As the return `ValType pop()` may be different from `double`, ensure a matching type to `%f`.

   ```
   // printf("= %f\n", pop(nums))
   printf("= %f\n", (double) pop(nums))
   ```
6. For debugging, using `"%e"` is more illuminating.

   ```
   // printf("= %f\n", (double) pop(nums))
   printf("= %e\n", (double) pop(nums))
   ```

---

Quite a bit more exist to review, but GTG.

Answer (score 7):

First, things my compiler complains about with warnings turned on:

- As PellMel has already said, you haven't declared the return type of `main`. It's good practice to do so.
- In `calculating.c` you forgot to include `ctype.h`. This header contains declarations for `isspace` and `isdigit` among others.
- In addition, you forgot to include `stdio.h` in `stack.c`, where you use `printf`.

So on to running your program. The first thing I noticed was the following line:

> ```
> sh: cls: command not found
> ```

In your program, you use `system("cls")` to clear the screen. This is unfortunately not cross platform compatible, as the `cls` command is Windows specific. Let me quote [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/123411/64958) by @Edward on the topic.

> There are two reasons not to use `system("cls")` or `system("pause")`. The first is that it is not portable to other operating systems which you may or may not care about now. The second is that it's a security hole, which you absolutely **must** care about. Specifically, if some program is defined and named `cls` or `pause`, your program will execute that program instead of what you intend, and that other program could be anything.

The most common library for cross platform advanced console manipulation is [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). There is a Windows version available from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm).

On the other hand, I don't think clearing the screen is necessary at all from a user experience perspective. Think of any interactive interpreter you might have used: `python`, `irb`, or even `cmd`. After one line of input is received, a new one can be entered without the screen being cleared. This is useful because the user might want to look at their previous calculations when making new ones. Therefore, I think an interaction between user and program should look more similar to this:

```
Calculator by luckystrrrike. Type quit to exit.
expression> 2 * 3 =
= 6
expression> 6 + 1 =
= 7
expression> quit
```

Alternatively, a user could also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to exit the program.

If you choose to go down the route of making the calculator more "interpreter like", adding line history etc seems like the next step. Line history is where pressing up on the keyboard scrolls through previously entered lines, which could be really helpful, e.g. if you typed something out wrong. You could implement this by yourself, but fortunately there is a library readily available for this as well called [readline](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm).

Turning to the expression syntax, I wonder why they have to be terminated by `=` instead of a newline. For a user (at least me), newlines are a more intuitive terminator than the equals sign, but YMMV.

Overall, writing a calculator is an interesting project to learn about parsing I've done myself. I think you've done a good job.

Comment: Furthermore, with a check for [`_isatty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4s0ddew.aspx) or [`isatty()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html), you could avoid printing any prompt at all when accepting expressions piped to stdin.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call the functions from `<ctype.h>` with a `char` as an argument -- always cast it to `unsigned char`. See [the NetBSD documentation](https://man.netbsd.org/ctype.3) for an explanation.

Comment: Even better: always compile with `unsigned char` as the default char type. `cl.exe` switch is `/J`.